# Jasmine does not reset spy after each test spec

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, junit, jasmine

I have the following spec.

```
describe("SN.ExitHistory", function() {

    var exitHistory;

    beforeEach(function() {

    SN.Utils = jasmine.createSpy("utils").andCallFake(function() {
        function readSNCookie(cookieName, key) {
            return "google.com";
        }

        function isUndefinedOrNull(param) {
            return (param == null) || (param === "null");
        }

        function createSNCookie(snCookieName, key, value, lifeTime) {

        }

        var me = {
            readSNCookie : readSNCookie,
            isUndefinedOrNull : isUndefinedOrNull,
            createSNCookie : createSNCookie
        };
        return me;

    })();

    exitHistory = SN.ExitHistory();

    });

    it("return last exit link", function() {
        expect(exitHistory.getLastExitLink()).toEqual("google.com");
    });

 });
```

`exitHistory.getLastExitLink` internally use `SN.Utils`.

After the test is done Jasmine does not remove the spy object utils. In next test suite also I can see the same utils present. Is there any way to reset the spy object after each test is done?

Instead of creating spy, if I create a new object for utils, behavior is same. Then what is the difference between a spy and actual object in this scenario.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem some time ago and after days of struggling I found the solution. If you use the other way your spy will be reseted, so try with

```
spyOn(SN, 'Utils');
```

Spies are described here:
https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies

Comment: `createSpy` is now deprecated and there is a comment in sources before `createSpy` definition that you should not use this internal method.

Comment: and this answer is right, by the way, it will solve author's problems

Comment: ah, sorry, it is `jasmine.Spy()` which is not allowed to be called:

> Note: Do <b>not</b> call `new jasmine.Spy()` directly - a spy must be created using `spyOn`, `jasmine.createSpy` or `jasmine.createSpyObj`

anyway, `spyOn` is the thing author needs. `createSpy` is only fits for spying functions, not object-bound methods.

Comment: This does not work with Jasmine 1.0.3 (and as far as I can tell from the 1.3 source code with 1.3 either): for my current 1.0.3 based test suite it says '<METHOD NAME> has already been spied upon'. I'm resetting the spy using `<OBJECT>.<METHOD>.wasCalled = false;` when testing further expectations.

Comment: @shaman.sir I don't know where you found the information that `createSpy` is deprecated - it serves a slightly different use than `spyOn` and does not say that in 1.3.1 comments

Comment: @DominicTobias you are right, though I noticed it in next comment that I was wrong, it was about `jasmine.Spy()` which was deprecated and seems to be completely removed now :).

Comment: @try-catch-finally the spy object has the `reset()` method. or it has not in `1.0.3`? 
Probably, author's problem is in creating a spy inside the call to `beforeEach` and not in a function that creates a spy. And why calling a fake immediately with `})();`... Should I add it as a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `spyOn` and declare your spies within a `before` block inside of a `describe` spec block and the spies will be cleaned up when each spec is torn down.

aSpec.js

```js
describe('something', () => {
    beforeAll(() => spyOn(someObject, 'someMethod').and.returnValue('foo'));
    it('is spied on', () => {
       expect(someObject.someMethod()).toEqual('foo');
    });
});
```

anotherSpec.js

```js
describe('something else', () => {
    beforeAll(() => spyOn(someObject, 'someMethod').and.returnValue('bar'));
    it('is spied on', () => {
       expect(someObject.someMethod()).toEqual('bar');
    });
});
```